# How to get offsetHeight then set it to 0 without callbacks?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have div with height 100px.
I need to get element height, save value in variable and then set element height to 0.
My problem is that I get final style value - 0.

```
let height = element.offsetHeight;
element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
element.style.maxHeight = 0;
```

I know that there is some method to get current value, something like this:

```
let height = element.offsetHeight;
someBrowserRenderingOrPositionFunction();
element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
element.style.maxHeight = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let height = element.getComputedStyle().height
```

The problem of `element.style.height` is that you get the height only if it has been written inside the html element tag with the `style` attribute.

```
getComputedStyle()
```

gives you the final style of the element as you see it on the webpage.

Comment: I found that actual reason to such behavior was my mistake. I was getting height of element yet not added to DOM.